# does Chromecast with google tv need Android TV receiver app for just casting?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, android-tv, google-tv, receiver

Do I need to develop [Android TV Receiver App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv_receiver) to cast from existing sender app to "Chromecast with google tv" device?

I thought just web receiver app would be okay for casting without registered android TV app just like Chromecast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to developer an Android TV receiver app to cast to the Chromecast with Google TV. A standard web receiver will work on this device the same as a typical device running the Android TV OS. The main reason to use the Cast Connect library to build an Android TV receiver app is if you already have an Android TV app and want to give a more robust casting experience (e.g., allowing users to control playback with their remote control or providing a UX that's easier with native Android code).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have another question. is additional action needed to cast to chromecast with google tv other than whitelisting device serial number? casue cast button for chromecast with google tv isn't shown on the sender app. Only buttons for older receivers are shown. I triple checked the serial numbers.

Comment: As far as I know, it should be the same as any Cast device (register the serial number and the package if it's not released yet). You could also double-check if other apps show the device (if they don't, then it's more likely a network or device issue).